# I am trying to integrate cyberSource with omnipay library. But reference_number request parameter does not generated

Tags: omnipay

I am trying to integrate cybeSource with omnipay library. 
But my reference_number request parameter does not generated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: add some code and your environment versions

Comment: I have fixed the issues adding transactionId parameter with my request parameters.